# Iteration through dictionary on list updates all elements instead of current one

Tags: python

I am generating a list of dictionaries through a list comprehension that just repeats the element x times accordingly to the input parameter `scope_1` .

When I iterate over this list of dictionaries, I add some new keys and values to it.
But instead of updating only current element of the list inside the iteration, it updates all elements (dicts) from the list, so I end it up with all elements having the same data from the last loop execution.

In order to check if I was creating the list properly, I re-created it manually hardcoded and added as a second return of my function `scope_2`, and this new list works fine. But I don't see any difference between the two lists to have different behavior.

```
def get_test_scope(request):
    repeat = request

    test_object = {}
    # Reads from file
    test_object["id"] = "ID-1"
    test_object["summary"] = "Summary-1"

    # Scope 1 from list comprehension
    scope_1 = [test_object for _ in range(repeat)]

    # Scope 2 created manually
    scope_2 = [
        {"id": "ID-2", "summary": "Summary-2"},
        {"id": "ID-2", "summary": "Summary-2"},
    ]
    return scope_1, scope_2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import random
    # how many times to replicate element inside list
    scope_1, scope_2 = get_test_scope(2)

    # Prints Scope 1 and Scope 2
    print(f"Scope_1: {scope_1}")
    print(f"Scope_2: {scope_2}")

    # Iterates over Scope 1 and add new key, value pairs to it
    # FAIL: Should update only current test element. But updates all the elements of the list in each iteration
    for index, test in enumerate(scope_1):
        test["run"] = index
        test["duration"] = random.randint(1, 10)
        print(f"Scope 1: Loop({index}): {scope_1}")

    # Iterates over Scope 2 and add new key, value pairs to it
    # OK: Adds only to the current test element. Items end it up with their respective values
    for index, test in enumerate(scope_2):
        test["run"] = index
        test["duration"] = random.randint(1, 10)
        print(f"Scope 2: Loop({index}): {scope_2}")
```

I have this ouput comparing Scope 1 and Scope 2. I could not spot the difference or understand the first behavior.

```
Scope_1: [{'id': 'ID-1', 'summary': 'Summary-1'}, {'id': 'ID-1', 'summary': 'Summary-1'}]
Scope_2: [{'id': 'ID-2', 'summary': 'Summary-2'}, {'id': 'ID-2', 'summary': 'Summary-2'}]
Scope 1: Loop(0): [{'id': 'ID-1', 'summary': 'Summary-1', 'run': 0, 'duration': 1}, {'id': 'ID-1', 'summary': 'Summary-1', 'run': 0, 'duration': 1}]
Scope 1: Loop(1): [{'id': 'ID-1', 'summary': 'Summary-1', 'run': 1, 'duration': 8}, {'id': 'ID-1', 'summary': 'Summary-1', 'run': 1, 'duration': 8}]
Scope 2: Loop(0): [{'id': 'ID-2', 'summary': 'Summary-2', 'run': 0, 'duration': 6}, {'id': 'ID-2', 'summary': 'Summary-2'}]
Scope 2: Loop(1): [{'id': 'ID-2', 'summary': 'Summary-2', 'run': 0, 'duration': 6}, {'id': 'ID-2', 'summary': 'Summary-2', 'run': 1, 'duration': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `scope_1 = [test_object for _ in range(repeat)]`, you are not creating copies of test_object. You are just making a list of references to the test_object. This means that both `scope_1[0]` and `scope_1[1]` point to the same dictionary.

To fix this, create a copy of the dictionary on the comprehension list:

```
scope_1 = [test_object.copy() for _ in range(repeat)]
```